# How can download image from retrofit response kotlin android

Tags: android, file-io, retrofit

**How can download image from retrofit response Kotlin**

i got response from like this

```
 "image_thumb": "http%3A%2F%2Fdemo.co%2Fflightrecord%2Fimages%2Fpassport%2Fthumb%2Fpassport-307199094910Koala.jpg"
```

**how can save image in device directory using FileOutputStream**

Comment: I think you need to decode your URL first like below
String decodedURL = URLDecoder.decode("URL", "UTF-8");

Comment: yes you are right i need decode url first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution

```
 if (response.body()?.data != null) {
                        val result = URLDecoder.decode(response.body()?.data?.get(0)?.dof!!, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
                        val image1 = URLDecoder.decode(response.body()?.data?.get(0)?.image_thumb!!, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
                        var imagePath: String

                        Glide.with(this)
                            .asBitmap()
                            .load(image1)
                            .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
                                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                                    val fos: FileOutputStream? =
                                        activity?.openFileOutput( response.body()?.data?.get(0)?.userid!!, AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE)
                                    resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fos)
                                    fos?.close()
                                    imagePath = activity?.applicationContext?.getFileStreamPath(response.body()?.data?.get(0)?.userid!!)?.absolutePath?.toUri()
                                        .toString()
                                    handler.passportInsert(
                                        PassportModelClass(
                                            response.body()?.data?.get(0)?.userid!!,
                                            response.body()?.data?.get(0)?.fistname!!,
                                            response.body()?.data?.get(0)?.surname!!,
                                            response.body()?.data?.get(0)?.nationality!!,
                                            result,
                                            response.body()?.data?.get(0)?.gender!!,
                                            imagePath,
                                            response.body()?.data?.get(0)?.age!!.toInt()
                                        )
                                    )
                                    binding.progress.isVisible = false
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "restore successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }
                                override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                                }
                            })
                    }
```